# Encoded CSV with sqlToCsv package not working with non-ASCII characters

Tags: go, encoding, utf-8, export-to-csv

I am using package "github.com/jeffyi/sqltocsv" to export MSSql rows to CSV files.

My problem is that special characters end up wrong way:

ü as Ć¼
ä as Ć¤
etc..

I have read the sqltocsv package multiple times and I just don't get that when and where is it going wrong.

i have logged output to console, before exporting data comes out from DB as UTF-8 but on adding to CSV it gets messed up.

I have tryed to use package "encoding/csv" to convert my data to csv file. 
(without any success)

Here's how I use sqlToCsv package:

```
rows, _ := db.Query(sqlQuery)

            csvConverter := sqltocsv.New(rows)
            csvConverter.Delimiter = ';'
            csvConverter.TimeFormat = time.RFC822

            csvConverter.WriteFile(directory + "/" + fileName)
```

so in the end result should all characters be as they are:

ü as ü (not Ć¼ )
ä as ä (not Ć¤ )

Comment: How exactly are you confirming the final CSV? With a text editor/hex editor, or *Excel*…?

Comment: Excel is that stupid thing what does not get that it should be in UTF-8.
I remember that in php and node i somehow managed to give "headers" with file and then it was smart enough to open that CSV with right encoding.

Other things get that those characters belong to UTF-8 and show them correctly (Notepad++, VS code, also default notepad show it correctly)

Comment: So, your problem is Excel related, not Go related, yes?

Comment: I think that its Go, smarter editors just read the file before opening and detect utf8 in them, but excel is stupid and wants somekind of "flag" to open it as utf8..

Comment: Yes, Excel notoriously sucks when it comes to encodings. Believe it or not, there is no 100% foolproof method to produce a CSV file that *all versions of Excel* will read identically. At best you can produce a CSV file that *a particular version of Excel* (say, anything after 2012 on Windows) will read as expected. Either that, or you produce a standards compliant CSV file and let Excel users figure it out for themselves, or you provide an XLSX file as alternative.